# Has glitchy any intentional meaning/feeling?

Tags: meaning

I am coding one template in my job, and this time the client is from Canada.

This template is going to the version three, because of some adjusts...

In the last review, they wrote about one scroll animation:

> `ALL TRANSITIONS`
>
> `The speed is good`
>
> `remove the lock in place > Allow for continuous scrolling.`
>
> `The lock in place isnt reacting well`
>   `Too glitchy - Too sensitive`

I had never seen the `glitchy` word before, then I googled it and found this [meaning.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glitchy)

---

To me, this word looks like an air of some intentional thinking behind it. I don't know! Then, I am asking:

Is it just another normal word just uncommon in use? Or has it another *feeling* behind, like disappointment maybe?

And where is it commom to use?

Thanks

Comment: It just means error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of **glitchy** here seems to mean **jumpy**.

Your scrolling animation is **too sensitive** (from the text) and so might appear to the user to jump up and down instead of a smooth steady scroll where their eye can follow the lines their reading s it scrolls.  Instead, the screen will **appear to jump**, and the user has to find their place again.

**Glitchy** has a **static-y**, **jump-y** feel to it, like when a gear catches then slips then catches again, having an intermittent and not continuous feel.